# How to zoom Heatmap.js with Legend & Tooltip

Tags: tooltip, zooming, heatmap

Here i'm working with heatmaps, i tried with lot of examples, then I come across [Heatmap.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) and it worked. Now I'm working on an example, [heatmap with tooltip](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-legend-tooltip.html). But i need to implement "Zoom" option in the same example. How can I zoom, the high intensity area in heatmap.

Please suggest a method. Thanks in advance.